# Problems with discord.js async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-modules

I'm having an error with a discord.js dependant function I made:

```
async function timeoutUser(guildMember, exp, reason) {
  try {
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const timeoutDuration = (exp - now) * 1000;

    console.log(`Timing out ${guildMember} in ${timeoutDuration} milliseconds for reason: ${reason}`);
    
    await guildMember.timeout({timeoutDuration, reason});
    console.log(`Successfully timed out ${guildMember} for ${timeoutDuration / 1000} seconds. Reason: ${reason}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to timeout user with Discord ID ${guildMember}: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Error: Failed to remove timeout for user with Discord ID 785346463915311176: TypeError: guildMember.timeout is not a function
```

The full error is shown above. I'm using this as documented in the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What is `guildMember`? How do you execute `timeoutUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates made, guildMember is not an instance of GuildMember:

```
async function timeoutUser(discordId, exp, reason) {
  try {
    const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const timeoutDuration = (exp - now) * 1000;

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(TxAdminConfig.targetServerId);
    if (!guild) {
      console.error('Target server not found');
      return;
    }
  
    const member = await guild.members.fetch(discordId).catch(() => null);
    if (!member) {
      console.log(`User with Discord ID ${discordId} not found in the guild`);
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Timing out Discord ID ${discordId} in ${timeoutDuration} milliseconds for reason: ${reason}`);
    
    await member.timeout(timeoutDuration, `txAdmin Ban: ${reason}`);
    console.log(`Successfully timed out Discord ID ${discordId} for ${timeoutDuration / 1000} seconds. Reason: ${reason}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to timeout user with Discord ID ${discordId}: ${error}`);
  }
}
```